# when i set icon to drawer menu then the drawer menu become slow in android

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-xml

> I'm new in Android
>
> when i set icon in drawer_menu.xml code then after when i open the
>   navigation drawer menu it open slowly why?
>
> If any one have answer to this question or ever faced this type of
>   issues then plz reply to this question.

**Here is my drawer_menu.xml code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/home_id"
            android:icon="@drawable/home"
            android:title="Home"></item>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/id_setting"
            android:icon="@drawable/setting"
            android:title="Settings"></item>
    </group>

    <item android:title="Others">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/notifications"
                android:icon="@drawable/noti"
                android:title="Notifications"></item>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/about_us"
                android:icon="@drawable/aboutus"
                android:title="About us"></item>
        </menu>

    </item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of icon?
use 300*300